# How to replace class with mock in DI? Phalcon + Codeception

Tags: dependency-injection, phalcon, codeception

I try writing functional tests for my controllers using Codeception testing framework. I want to replace real service in DI with fake one.

Controller code example:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class IndexController extends ControllerBase
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
    // some logic here
    $service = $this->getDI()->get('myService');
    $service->doSomething();
    // some logic here
  }
}
```

Test code example:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Functional;

class IndexControllerCest
{
  public function testIndexAction(FunctionalTester $I)
  {
    // Here i want to mock myService, replace real object that in controller with fake one
    $I->amOnRoute('index.route');
  }
}
```

I already try different combinations with Codeception Phalcon module like `addServiceToContainer`.
I setup Codeception using bootstrap.php file almost the same as for real app.

Phalcon version: 3.4.1
Codeception version: 3.1

So my question in last code fragment on comment section. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would like suggest you start from creating a separated helpers to create and inject dependencies as follows:

```
# functional.suite.yml
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Helper\MyService
        - Phalcon:
            part: services
            # path to the bootstrap
            bootstrap: 'app/config/bootstrap.php'
        # Another modules ...
```

Create a separated service:

```
<?php
namespace Helper;

use Codeception\Module;

/** @var \Codeception\Module\Phalcon */
protected $phalcon;

class MyService extends Module
{
  public function _initialize()
  {
      $this->phalcon = $this->getModule('Phalcon');
  }

  public function haveMyServiceInDi()
  {
    $this->phalcon->addServiceToContainer(
      'myService',
      ['className' => '\My\Awesome\Service']
    );
  }
}
```

And use it in tests as follows:

```
<?php
namespace App\Functional;

use Helper\MyService;

class IndexControllerCest
{
  /** @var MyService */
  protected $myService;

  protected function _inject(MyService $myService)
  {
      $this->myService = $myService;
  }

  public function testIndexAction(FunctionalTester $I)
  {
    $I->wantTo(
      'mock myService, replace real object that in controller with fake one'
    );

    $this->myService->haveMyServiceInDi();
    $I->amOnRoute('index.route');
  }
}
```